# Crystal PCB track

Tags: pcb-design, crystal, layout

This is my current PCB crystal set up. The crystal run at 16 Mhz. Any thoughts/comment?

[image]

Links:

MCU - [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c1233h6pm.pdf)

TI PCB guideline Tiva C - [Here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spma059/spma059.pdf)

Comment: Can you add a link to the MCU's datasheet?

Comment: At 16MHz u shouldn't have issues. But u can make things better. You should relocate crystal closer to MCU. Also, it seems you connect your capacitors on your ground plane by a via. Try to make a local ground and so, connect it to your ground plane. But, as I said, for 16MHz I think it's okay

Comment: The POV on previous capture was bad, we couldn't see the high speed USB differential pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment would be, What is your total trace Length, it is looking maybe a bit long?  From the PCB Guideline:

3.7.2 Crystal Oscillator Circuit Layout

The key layout objectives should be to minimize both the loop area of the oscillator signals and the overall trace length. A poor oscillator layout can result in unreliable or inaccurate oscillator operation and can also be a noise source. Ideal trace length is less than 0.25 in or 6 mm. Do not exceed 0.75 in or 18 mm.

Comment: That what I thought, but is I bring the crystal closer the MCU, isn't there a chance that the crystal will affect the USB lines. Ortherwise, I could move the USB connector.

Comment: Move the osc to the left without moving it up. Move those other two components if needed.

Comment: Finaly, I choose to move the USB connector, the crystal is a vital part of the design, therefore I don't want to be near the worst value.

Comment: I also recommend widening the traces as much as possible. This decreases the resistance and will give you a nicer oscillation

Comment: Unrelated, but your USB Traces do not appear to have the correct width / spacing to achieve the correct impedance nor do you have a TVS (which may or may not be needed depending on your intended usage.)